# Command line tools/bash scripts with state

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

I'm trying to write a simple single-file shell script that's supposed to do a google search and output the titles of the first five results:

```
> lookup search "Stack Overflow"
100 results

1. Stack overflow
www.stackoverflow.com
(description)

2. ...
```

Then the user is supposed to be able to enter:

```
> lookup go 1
```

and it will open up the user's command line browser of choice to the first result.

However, this requires the script to "remember" the results of the last command.

What is the best way to do this?  Should I save the results as an environment variable?  (If so, this would involve sourcing the script instead of invoking it in its own subshell, which might be against security conventions/unsafe?  I have no idea really)  Should I save the results in a temporary text file?

A similar functionality exists in [geeknote](http://geeknote.me), but it's implemented in python and I might have to end up digging through it to find out where it does this; however, I'm not even totally sure that the solution would apply to me.

Comment: What do you do if you open two terminals and run different searches in each?

Comment: @AdamBatkin I'd leave that behavior undefined, but it'd be (marginally) nicer if searching on one terminal did not affect another terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a dot file to save the info, in the same way your shell can save cmds in the .history file across logins.

If you're comfortable ensuring that the data is clean/safe for evaluating  before writing it to the file you could set it up so the values are easily available for sourcing in your script. If you saved them in t.var, you'd probably want ~/.yourprogram or somesuch

```
$ cat t.var 
A=yahoo.com
B=google.com
```

You can then read them in via dot: .

```
$ cat ./s.sh
#!/bin/bash
. t.var
echo ${A}
```

And voila:

```
$ bash ./s.sh 
yahoo.com
```

You'd just need to map names to positions.

```
#!/bin/bash
. t.var
case "$1" in
 1 )
   echo $A;;
 2 )
   echo $B;;
esac
```

There seems to be a tradeoff of parsing the data vs ease of use of getting it back out. The above is just one way.